# Find type of nullable properties via reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, nullable

I examine the properties of an object via reflection and continue processing the data type of each property. Here is my (reduced) source:

```
private void ExamineObject(object o)
{
  Type type = default(Type);
  Type propertyType = default(Type);
  PropertyInfo[] propertyInfo = null;

  type = o.GetType();

  propertyInfo = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.GetProperty |
                                    BindingFlags.Public |
                                    BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                    BindingFlags.Instance);
  // Loop over all properties
  for (int propertyInfoIndex = 0; propertyInfoIndex <= propertyInfo.Length - 1; propertyInfoIndex++)
  {
    propertyType = propertyInfo[propertyInfoIndex].PropertyType;
  }
}
```

My problem is, that I newly need to handle nullable properties, but I have no clue how to get the type of a nullable property.

Comment: i find good Answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8550614/5996253) worth trying!!

Answer (score 153, accepted):

possible solution:

```
    propertyType = propertyInfo[propertyInfoIndex].PropertyType;
    if (propertyType.IsGenericType &&
        propertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
    {
      propertyType = propertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
    }
```

Comment: The correct check for Nullables is also mentioned on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366789.aspx. There, you can find some more resources on the topic, if needed.

Comment: **Can be done in one line!** : `propertyType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propertyType) ?? propertyType`

Comment: `propertyType.IsGenericType` is required indeed before `propertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()`, otherwise an exception is thrown. +1

Answer (score 39):

**`Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(fi.FieldType)`** will do the work for you check below code for do the thing you want

```
System.Reflection.FieldInfo[] fieldsInfos = typeof(NullWeAre).GetFields();

        foreach (System.Reflection.FieldInfo fi in fieldsInfos)
        {
            if (fi.FieldType.IsGenericType
                && fi.FieldType.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof(Nullable<>)))
            {
                // We are dealing with a generic type that is nullable
                Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}, Type: {1}", fi.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(fi.FieldType));
            }

    }
```

Comment: I like the `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type)` solution because it is more explicit than `type.GetGenericArguments()[0]`, at least in this case.

Comment: You **don't need to check IsGenericType and GetGenericTypeDefinition**, `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType` already do that natively. GetUnderlyingType is returning null when the type is not Nullable<> (source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.nullable.getunderlyingtype(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 21):

```
foreach (var info in typeof(T).GetProperties())
{
  var type = info.PropertyType;
  var underlyingType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type);
  var returnType = underlyingType ?? type;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

As pointed out by  [Yves M.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1480391/yves-m) it is as simple as below.

```
var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();

  foreach (var prop in properties)
  {
     var propType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType;
     var dataType = propType.Name;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using a loop to go through all class properties to get the property type. I use the following code:

```
public Dictionary<string, string> GetClassFields(TEntity obj)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> dctClassFields = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    foreach (PropertyInfo property in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        if (property.PropertyType.IsGenericType && property.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>) && property.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments().Length > 0)
            dctClassFields.Add(property.Name, property.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0].FullName);
        else
            dctClassFields.Add(property.Name, property.PropertyType.FullName);
    }

    return dctClassFields;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This method is easy, fast and safe

```
public static class PropertyInfoExtension {
    public static bool IsNullableProperty(this PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
        => propertyInfo.PropertyType.Name.IndexOf("Nullable`", StringComparison.Ordinal) > -1;
}
```