# C# Reflection: How to get the type of a Nullable<int>?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, typeof, gettype

What I want to do is something like this:

```
switch( myObject.GetType().GetProperty( "id") )
{
    case ??: 
        // when Nullable<Int32>, do this
    case ??:
        // when string, do this
    case ??:
        // when Nullable<bool>, do this
```

What path under object.GetType() would have the string name of the datatype that I could compare using a case statement?  I need to know the type so I can have one of many Convert.ToInt32( string ) that will set the value of myObject using Reflection.

Comment: This is almost definitely doing things wrong. Why can't you take advantage of polymorphism, rather than using a giant switch statement?

Comment: If you're suggesting to create several functions with different parameter types, I could.  In this case, I am copying a set of properties of different types from one object to another where one is always a string type.  So, I need to convert the value to assign it.  That and I have very little experience with Reflection.

Comment: @CodyGray he might be doing something with regards to reflection, say writing his own ORM. Or writing a custom serializer for all this DAOs, you never know.

Comment: That's why it is "almost definitely", rather than "certainly". And even if he is doing those things, there are arguments to be made about why those are also wrong. Much has been written about why ORM is a poor database pattern, and I don't see any compelling reason why you could not write a serializer that used polymorphic types. The purpose of the comment was to get Dr. Zim to *think* about whether this is really the best option, that's why it was a comment not an answer. @nawfal

Comment: @CodyGray I see your point on *caution*, the "definite" there feels like a strong word though to put across your point. I dont believe ORMs are poor (quite the opposite) and can see where custom serialization implementation would require this. The other day I was writing a sync framework for syncing data from two different sources, it took me much less time to reflect on members than go and implement an interface on all the types in project, if you need it quick and dirty. Along those lines.. When convention over configuration makes sense... Etc. Shoehorning OOP everywhere is a bad idea.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Update: Looks like C# 7 will support switching on `Type`s as the asker of this question was trying to do. It's a little different though so watch out for syntax landmines.

You don't need a string name to compare it:

```
if (myObject.GetType().GetProperty("id").PropertyType == typeof(Nullable<Int32>))
    // when Nullable<Int32>, do this
else if (myObject.GetType().GetProperty("id").PropertyType == typeof(string))
    // when string, do this
else if (myObject.GetType().GetProperty("id").PropertyType == typeof(Nullable<bool>))
    // when Nullable<bool>, do this
```

Comment: Are you sure you compare .GetType() to typeof( Nullable<Int32>) or is it a property under GetType()?  Assuming int? and Nullable<Int32> are the same type, a.GetType() != typeof( Nullable<Int32>).

Comment: You probably have to do this with `if` statements, rather than in a `switch` statement. But, like you, I've never done this before. It looks like an anti-pattern to me.

Comment: VS studio will have panic attack over the above code switch(myObject.GetType()) will show an IDE error of "Value of integral type expected" and case typeof(XXX) will show an IDE error of "Constant Value is expected"

Comment: Had to use `myObject.GetType().GetProperty("ID").PropertyType == typeof( Nullable<Int64>)` in my special circumstance, but it worked.  Thanks.

Comment: Just like Eric said, there is no boxed `Nullable<T>`. Nullables get boxed as the underlying type if they are not null, or `null` which is typeless if they are. Thus your code won't work.

Comment: This structure exists. But `GetType()` will never return `Nullable<T>`, since `GetType()` operates on boxed values, and nullable values don't get boxed as `Nullable<T>`. So both the first and the third `if` in your example will never be satisfied.

Comment: He worked on `myObject.GetType().GetProperty("ID").PropertyType`. The static type of the property can be `Nullable<T>`, it's just `GetType()` that can't return a nullable.

Comment: Agree with @CodesInChaos & @nawfal. Answer is misleading. `GetType()` operates on a boxed value. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/how-to-identify-a-nullable-type

Comment: Corrected answer several years too late to help the asker, but people keep coming here so hopefully it'll help someone else.

Answer (score 96):

I've been using the following type of code to check if the type is nullable and to get the actual type:

```
if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
{
    return Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type);
}
```

If the type is e.g. Nullable this code returns the int part (underlying type). If you just need to convert object into specific type you could use [`System.Convert.ChangeType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08.aspx) method.

Comment: +1 and worth noting this method does the same check inside and returns null if the given type is not `typeof(Nullable<>)` so doing a null check afterwards instead of the if statement would also work.

Answer (score 19):

The question is very confusing. Is "myObject" the object that might be a nullable int?  Or is the property "id" possibly of type nullable int?

If the former, your question cannot be answered because it presupposes a falsehood. There is no such thing as a boxed nullable int.  I note that all of the answers which propose `if (myobject.GetType() == typeof(int?))` are therefore incorrect; the condition will never be true.

When you convert a nullable int to object, either it becomes a null reference (if the nullable int had no value) or it becomes a boxed int.  There is no way to determine if an object contains a nullable int because an object *never* contains a nullable int.

If the latter, compare the *property type* to `typeof(int?)`. You cannot use a switch; only constants may be used for switch cases and types are not constants.

All that said, this is a bad code smell. Why are you using reflection in the first place?

Comment: Update: in C# 7, switch statements no-longer require constant expressions :)

Comment: And provide a mechanism for switching on types. That feature was first proposed in... 2001? I think.  So, 16 years, not bad.

Comment: _"types are not constants"_   I would have thought that types would be constant since they are kind of hard to change during runtime (sans DLR). This probably explains (or justifies/is justified by) all of the `string` types being changed to `ReadOnlySpan<char>` =/

Answer (score 2):

In .net, instances of value types are just collections of bits, with no associated type information.  For every value type other than `Nullable<T>`, however, the system also auto-generates a corresponding class type which derives from `System.ValueType`.  A widening conversion exists from the value type to the auto-generated class type, and a narrowing conversion from the auto-generated class type to the value type.  In the case of `Nullable<T>`, there is no corresponding auto-generated class type with conversions to/from the value type; instead, widening conversions exist in both directions between `Nullable<T>` and the class type associated with `T`.

As far as I can tell, this weird behavior was implemented to allow comparisons between `null` and an empty `Nullable<T>` to return true.

Answer (score -1):

As @Cody Gray said if statements would probably be the best way

```
var t = myObject.GetType();

if (t == typeof(Nullable<int>))
{ }
else if (t == typeof(string))
{}
else if (t==typeof(Nullable<bool>))
{}
```

Comment: interestingly enough, when `int? a = 3` then `typeof( a)` is "System.Int32"

Comment: @Dr.Zim: See explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/785358/nullable-type-is-not-a-nullable-type

Comment: @Dr.Zim `typeof(a)` doesn't even compile. It's `a.GetType()` that returns `int`.

Comment: Wrong answer. `myObject.GetType` will always give `int` if it is declared either as `int` or `int?`