# How to switch on types with/when using nullable types?

Tags: c#, .net-core, switch-statement, nullable, c#-8.0

I know [this question has been asked multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298976/is-there-a-better-alternative-than-this-to-switch-on-type) before, but [I've](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7252186/15488899) [checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542793/how-to-use-switch-case-on-a-type) [all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298976/is-there-a-better-alternative-than-this-to-switch-on-type/299001#299001) [I](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149788/c-sharp-switch-on-object-type-at-runtime) [could](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478464/c-sharp-switch-on-type/4478490#4478490)  [not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298976/is-there-a-better-alternative-than-this-to-switch-on-type) [find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10115028/best-way-to-switch-behavior-based-on-type) [any solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551773/c-sharp-which-is-the-best-alternative-to-switch-on-type) there, because none of this specifically handles/talks about nullable types.

### Use case

I want to generate test data dynamically. To do this the `value` I pass in can have different types and I need to convert it (via `CreateSomething`) in some data type e.g. a specially formatted string. For this, I have the helper function shown below.
An example would be to generate an example XML file for later use in testing against the system in production. The `value` is then used to assert the correct expected output.

Note that for some types I need special handling, such as converting bools to integers (as you can see below), that's why I need a switch. In addition, the egnerated string mentions the type of the test data (though it does not match all types you have in C#/uses other names, e.g. booleans are defined as integers).

### Possible example

With C# 8.0 this is possible:

```cs
public static string GetSomething(object? value) =>
    value switch
    {
        bool boolValue => CreateSomething("Integer", boolValue
            ? 1
            : 0),
        string stringValue => CreateSomething("String", stringValue),
        int numericValue => CreateSomething("String", numericValue.ToString()),
        null => CreateSomething("String", value),
        _ => throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(value))
    };
```

`CreateSomething` is defined as this:

```cs
string CreateSomething(string customType, object? value)
```

### Question

However, as for the `null` case (maked above), I further want to handle the type.
As you can see with the other cases, I want to pass `Integer` in there for all `bool` values as the first parameter, and `String` for all others.
Of course, the `value` is and stays `null`, but that is about to be expected, I just want to keep the information/pass the information on about what type it should expect/define the thing in my test data, because otherwise it is defined as another data type and thus does not produce as real test data as it could (without disregarding the type).

### Tries

I thought of using a second switch statement in there/or use `.GetType`, but of course that doe snot work as `.GetType` on `null` throws a `NullReferenceException`.
I also looked at getting the underlying type of a nullable via [`Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(value)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8550614/15488899), but that did not work either. And [this question to get the type from `null`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254461/net-how-do-you-get-the-type-of-a-null-object#254488) only has answers using Generics, which I don't want in my case.
After all, I do have this nice C# switch [type pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/pattern-matching#type-tests) statement I can use for all types - why can't I also use it for nullable types?

### Idea solution

After all, this would be ideal:

```cs
/* Code does not work! Only demonstration! */
public static string GetSomething(object? value) =>
    value switch
    {
        bool? boolValue => CreateSomething("Integer", boolValue == null
            ? null : (boolValue ? 1 : 0),
        string? stringValue => CreateSomething("String", stringValue),
        int? numericValue => CreateSomething("String", numericValue?.ToString()),
        _ => throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(value))
    };
```

Of course, I tried that and it also did not work.

It just shows me the error CS8400 ("Feature type pattern is not available in C# 8.0. Please use language version 9.0 or higher.") and "Type test pattern requires variable designation or discard after.".
And even if I use C# 9 it breaks the syntax while not showing me any explicit compiler error anymore.

Comment: What you are trying to accomplish is not very clear. Could you give some examples of calling your method and what you expect them to do?

Comment: I think you'd have to include the type you're expecting, no? If your last example worked, any time you'd pass `null`, the `bool?` pattern would match since `null` contains no storage information. There's no way to tell if `null` is an `int?` or a `bool?` or a `Foo?` since it's not a reference to anything.

Comment: @DM Yeah, thanks, apparently there is no way to make it behave as I want it. It seems I need to use Generics or a `Type` parameter to pass-through the type.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to switch on nullable types.  That won't work.  Suppose someone called your function like this:

```
GetSomething(null);
```

What should the `GetSomething` function treat that as?  A nullable bool?  A nullable int?  There's no way to tell.

You need to check for null first and then treat the other possibilities as normal types.  Maybe like this?

```
public static string GetSomething(object? value)
{
    if (value == null)
        return "null";

    return value switch
    {
        bool boolValue     => CreateSomething("Integer", boolValue ? 1 : 0),
        string stringValue => CreateSomething("String",  stringValue),
        int numericValue   => CreateSomething("String",  numericValue.ToString()),
        null               => CreateSomething("String",  value),
        _                  => throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(value))
    };
}
```

If you really need something different for a nulled bool vs a nulled int, then you will need to also pass in the datatype that you were expecting to read.  Like this

```
public static string GetSomething(object? value, Type expectedType)
```

Comment: `null               => CreateSomething("String",  value),` already handles the same, respectively the if switch (in the first first line) you introduced, so this code is no differet than mine.

Comment: It is different from yours in that it switches on `bool`, `int`, `string`, not `bool?`, `int?`, and `string?`  Admittedly I was guessing that your intent was to somehow show different behavior from a `bool?` that was null vs an `int?` that was null.  If you are OK with having the same value returned for anything that is null, then my first approach (minus the redundant null check) is fine.  If you need distinct behavior from a null value for an expected  `bool` vs a null for an expected `int`, then you will have to pass in type information.