# IsPrimitive doesn't include nullable primitive values

Tags: c#, types, primitive

I want to check if a Type is primitive or not and used the following code:

```
return type.IsValueType && type.IsPrimitive;
```

This works fine aslong as the primitive isnt nullable. For example int?, how can I check if the type is a nullable primitive type? (FYI: `type.IsPrimitive == false` on int?)

Comment: You need to identify nullable types and then drill into them to get the closed generic type out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644587/find-type-of-nullable-properties-via-reflection `Nullable<T>` isn't primitive, it's just a `struct` wrapper around other `struct` types with extra compiler support.

Comment: That `int?` is a shorthand for `Nullable<int>`, so it is correct that it is not reported as primitive.

Comment: Nullables use the Generic type, which is not primitive by definition. Try the bellow suggestions :)

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? I'm asking because often there are better approaches than using reflection.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I am doing a deep clone and using the following (http://stackoverflow.com/a/11308879/2598770) but I want to modify it a bit and noticed that the check of IsPrimitive doesnt care about nullable ints.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From MSDN:

> The primitive types are Boolean, Byte, SByte, Int16, UInt16, Int32,
>   UInt32, Int64, UInt64, IntPtr, UIntPtr, Char, Double, and Single.

So basically you should expect `Nullable<Int32>` to *not* be a primitive type.

You could use [`Nullable.GetUnderlyingType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullable.getunderlyingtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to "extract" `Int32` from `Nullable<Int32>`.

Comment: Thx for the Nullable.GetUnderlyingType, you dont happen to know a way to check a custom collection if its type.IsArray and than cast it to array if it is? For example: CustomList<T> : IList<T>, IList, IEnumerable<T>

Comment: @RandRandom: This is a question-and-answer site; if that's your question then *post it as a question*, not as a comment.

Answer (score 14):

First you'll need to determine if it's `Nullable<>` and then you'll need to grab the nullable types:

```
if (type.IsGenericType
    && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>)
    && type.GetGenericArguments().Any(t => t.IsValueType && t.IsPrimitive))
{
    // it's a nullable primitive
}
```

<strike>Now, the aforementioned works, but not recursively. To get it to work recursively you'll need to put this into a method that you can call recursively for all types in `GetGenericArguments`. However, don't do that if it's not necessary.</strike>

That code may also be able to be converted to this:

```
if (type.GetGenericArguments().Any(t => t.IsValueType && t.IsPrimitive))
{
    // it's a nullable primitive
}
```

but the caveat there is that it may be a generic reference type and may not actually meet the *definition of primitive* for your needs. Again, remember, the aforementioned is more concise but could return a *false positive.*

Comment: The type arguments to a nullable type are never nullable types.

Comment: @EricLippert, so there won't be any concern for recursion right?

Comment: Correct; the type arguments to `Nullable<T>` at runtime are always straight-up value types, nothing fancy.

Answer (score 2):

The reason `IsPrimitive` fails on `Nullable<int>` (also known as `int?`) is that `Nullable<int>` is not a primitive. It is an instance of a generic class [`Nullable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with the type parameter of `int`.

You can check if a number is a nullable primitive by verifying that

- It is a generic type,
- Its generic type definition is `Nullable<>`, and
- Its generic parameter type `IsPrimitive`.