# How can I initialize a System.Nullable<Int32>?

Tags: c#, .net

I need a Nullable type but how do I initialize such a variable? Whenever I try to do this it automatically converts to a normal Int32.

```
Nullable<Int32> nullableInt32 = new Nullable<Int32>(3);
Console.WriteLine(nullableInt32.GetType()); // gives me System.Int32
```

Is this a bug? How can I actually initalize the Nullable?

Comment: (`int? nullableInt32 = 3` is a quicker way of writing what you needed...). The fun part here is that `GetType()` boxes the value type it's called on (as it's a non-virtual method defined on `object`), and a `Nullable<int>` boxes to a normal `int`. So `GetType` ends up being called on a boxed `int`, and so returns `int`. This is just an annoying side-effect of `GetType`: you initialised a `Nullable<int>` correctly.

Answer (score 5):

From [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types#how-to-identify-a-nullable-value-type):

> If you want to determine whether an instance is of a nullable value type, don't use the Object.GetType method to get a Type instance to be tested with the preceding code. When you call the Object.GetType method on an instance of a nullable value type, the instance is boxed to Object. As boxing of a non-null instance of a nullable value type is equivalent to boxing of a value of the underlying type, GetType returns a Type instance that represents the underlying type of a nullable value type.

So your `int?` gets boxed to `int`, and `GetType()` is called on the boxed instance.

Unless you know the type at compile time and use `typeof`, there is no way to get a type of a nullable object:

```
var type = typeof(int?);
```

In practice this shouldn't matter because if you don't know the type at compile time, it means you're using some sort of type erasure (i.e. a cast to object), and that means boxing, and nullable value types don't exist there. You can't use polymorphism because that doesn't work with value types.

If you think you have a valid need for this, feel free to explain your use case in the comments.

Comment: ("*there is no way to get a type of a nullable object*" -- strictly speaking you can do stuff like `typeof(int?).GetGenericTypeDefinition().MakeGenericType(someType)`, but like you said, why would you?)

Comment: For particular reason why one would like to have instance of nullable type  check plenty of similar questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644587/find-type-of-nullable-properties-via-reflection - after you get type of a property it is easier to compare it to value at hand than digging into type...